# How to tell if an app is a Winforms app or WPF app by looking at project properties

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

When I look at the project properties in Visual Studio for my particular project, there is a field called Output Type which says Windows Application. Does that automatically tell me that it's a WinForms application? I'm trying to find a way to determine right away if the project is a Winforms application. Yes, I can look at the files and determine that by looking at the forms. But I'm wondering if there is a more obvious way to determine that by simply looking at a project's properties.

The other reason I'm asking is because when I look at the project properties of a WPF application, the Output Type is also Windows Application. The way to determine that it's a WPF app is by looking for XAML files. So is there a simpler technique to determine what type of app it is by looking at project properties?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can tell by what assemblies the project references.  Does it reference assemblies beneath `System.Windows.Forms`?  If so, it's WinForms.  If it only references namespaces beneath `System.Windows` other than `System.Windows.Forms`, then it's WPF.

Check the type of your main form -- is it a `System.Windows.Forms.Form`?  If so, it's a WinForms project.  If it's a `System.Windows.Window`, then it's WPF.

Answer (score 1):

I do it by using .NET Reflector (it has a 14 Day trial) there i look at the exe and open `Refrences` and there i can see if it says `System.Windows.Forms` or not.

Update:
Don't use .NET Reflector. Use JetBrains DotPeek its Free and has no trial.